# regex to match a word and the first parenteshis i find

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex to match a word like 'estabilidade' and then matches anything until it gets to the first parenteshis.
I already tried some regex that i found on internet, but i have difficulties to make my own regex, as i dont understand how it works very well.
Someone can help me?

The regex i already tried were:

```
re.search(r"([^\(]+)", resultado) -> trying to get just the parenteshis.
```

and

```
re.search(r"estabilidade((\s*|.*))\(+", resultado).group(1)
```

Real Example (need to pick up all the numbers inside the parenthesis, but knowing which word this number is related to. For instance, the first 7 is related to the sentence 'Procura por estabilidade'):

```
Procura por

estabilidade

(7)

É   assertivo(a)
com  os  outros

(5)

Procura convencer

os  outros

(7)

Espontaneamente

se  aproxima

dos outros

LIDERANÇA   INFLUÊ

10

9

(6)

Demonstra

diplomacia

(5)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input?

Comment: If you don't understand regular expressions, I would highly recommend this [video](https://youtu.be/K8L6KVGG-7o). It is very thorough and will get you started :)

Comment: Now i put the sample Rakesh! Thanks Michael, i will see this video!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my question, i solved the problem with the following regex, using the following tool indicate for one the users here (https://regex101.com/r/2qxa0y/1/)

```
((|.|[(]|\s)*)\((\d*)\)
```

Thanks to everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
estabilidade([^(]+)
```

It's using a negative character class, that's the key take away and a good tool in your bag to have.  `[]` is a character class.  It is a list of characters, if you put in `^` as the first character it's a list of characters *not* in there.  So `[^(]` means any character that isn't `(`.  Adding the `+` means at least 1 of the item to the left.  So, putting all that together we want at least 1 non `(`.

Here is it in Python:

```
import re

text = "hello estabilidade how are you today (at the farm)"
print (re.search("estabilidade([^(]+)", text).group(1))
```

Output:

```
 how are you today
```

Example to play with:

https://regex101.com/r/2qxa0y/1/

Here is a good site to learn some of the basic regex tricks, this will go a long way:  https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: To be honest i didnt understand the ^ (negative). The problem envolves to get the words inside the parenteshes. But i think this tool that you provide me will be the right one to find the answer that i'm looking for, as this, different from the other tool pointed here, allows me to test the example that I have on my code.

Comment: @LuizaRodrigues I'll update the ^ explanation a bit  :) happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.findall(r'([^()]+)\((\d+)\)', 'estabilidade_smth(10) estabilidade_other(20)')
Out[2]: [('estabilidade_smth', '10'), (' estabilidade_other', '20')]
```

Comment: I dont think so. It's something more like: estabilidade space/newline/anything that separeted the word from another letter that is visible  plus anything between plus number inside parenteshis. From your example it sounds the word has another one glue on it.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify which part of the matched string you want to check, so I included some more groups.

```
import re

s = 'hello there estabilidade this is just some text (yes it is)'
r = re.search(r"(estabilidade([.\S]+))\(", s)
print(r.group(1))  # "estabilidade this is just some text"
print(r.group(2))  # " this is just some text"
```

Comment: This didnt work as the word is follow by anything ( i saw that the dot matches any character except linebreaks). And the word can be follow by a linebreak